# Навигация на пхп

Tags: php, html, mysql

**Привет всем. Есть у меня такая функция:**

---

```
$p=intval($_GET['p']);
if (empty($p)){
$p=1;//страница
}
// навигатор по страницам 
function pages ($p){
global $id;
$res = mysql_query("select count(*) from news WHERE category=".$id."");// ищем все новости в категории
$row = mysql_result($res,0);
$news_num = "10";
$b = ceil(($row/$news_num)); // выводим по столько записей на страницу
$x=1;
while ($b>=$x){
if ($x==$p){
$news = mysql_query("select count(*) from news");
$pages_cat .= '<b>'.$x.'</b>';
} else {
$pages_cat .= '&nbsp;<a href="/category/'.$id.'/'.$x.'/"><b>'.$x.'</b></a>&nbsp;'; 
}  
$x++;
}
return $pages_cat;
}
```

---

Подскажите как доделать, что-бы, допустим $pages_cat выводила по 20 страниц, потом перевод строки, опять по 20 страниц и так пока не закончатся все записи в бд?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перед `$x++;` вставить:

```
 if ($x % 20 == 0) {
   $pages_cat .= '<br/>';
 }
```

Comment: Спасибо. Еще вопрос, как сделать текущую страницу на которой находиться пользователь не гиперссылкой?

Comment: $p надо чтоб содержала текущую страницу. Как-то так:
``<a href="/category/'.$id.'/?p='.$x.'"><b>'.$x.'</b></a>`` тогда ``$p=intval($_GET['p'])`` будет содержать текущую страницу. Ну либо если mod_rewrite'ом пользуетесь, то надо привести url к этому виду, чтоб была переменная p в _GET...

Comment: Спасибо но это знаю. mod_rewrite пользуюсь. просто скрипту передается уже значение страницы, он по ней и ищет и выводит новости. А как именно еще в скрипте указать и вывести не придумал)) Можете еще советами помочь=) У Вас ася или агент есть?

Comment: дак оно выводиться должно ``$pages_cat .= '<b>'.$x.'</b>';`` как раз выводит просто номер текущей страницы в списке, без ссылки.
зы с php знаком шапочно, рад, что здесь смог помочь, по другим вопросам вряд ли сумею... )

Comment: Ну ну))) Так уже помогли. И во тв чем прикол не хочет он так выводить $pages_cat .= '<b>'.$x.'</b>'; лично пишет пустота и надо еще как то значение x исключить из вывода то есть без ссылки

Comment: Ну я ж выше написал. нужно url привести к виду http://example.com/page.php?p=12 с помощью mod_rewrite, тогда в переменной $_GET['p'] появится значение страницы, которую открыли, и тогда уже if ($x == $p) сработает... ну далее по коду.